# Enable to use Tensorflow JS in the local computer

Tags: tensorflow.js

Goal:
Enable to run the tensorflow.js toxicity classifier demo in the local computer.

Problem:
Based on instruction "https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/149"

"You cannot call imports in a browser since browsers don't support such imports. Instead of loading tfjs as import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';, you need to import the library by either transpiring the node module and load it as a bundle using tools like webpack or load it using ready-to-use cdn mentioned here."

I have removed  "import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';" and started to use

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
```

But I still retrieve an error message

"Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: toxicity is not defined
    at predict (index.js:71)
    at index.js:95"

What part do I need to fix in order for everything to be working?
https://jsbin.com/wiqigayoqu/edit?html,js,console,output

Thank you!

Info:
*I'm new in Tensorflow.js
*The raw of the source code is located "https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/toxicity/demo"
*  https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/toxicity
*I don't know if you are enabled to see the code problem at jsbin and I have used the file index.html and index.js from "https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/toxicity/demo" and used it in my local computer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tkmkho

Apply the code as typescript in stackblitz.